# Huawei, 'OEM unlock' missing from developer options

Tags: fastboot, huawei, bootloader-lock

I want to unlock the bootloader of the Huawei phone. There is no 'OEM unlock' in the dev options.

When I go into bootloader: `fastboot flashing unlock` I get a message "command not allowed".

What can I do?

Comment: Possibly related: [Cannot unlock bootloader on Vodafone Smart Mini and Huawei P8 Lite](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175937/44325), [Can we consider Huawei phones as unrootable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232190/44325)

Comment: Yes, it gives possible solution....